# post method don't work in html form

Tags: php, html

I have this simple html form and using post method.

```
<html>
  <form action = "read.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name ="name">
        <input type="submit">
  </form>
</html>
```

and here is my php :

```
if(isset($_POST["name"])){
   echo "sent";
}
else
{
   echo "not sent";
}
```

when I run the code "not sent" message will appear.It seems everything is ok
but it doesn't work whereas GET method work correctly and show the "sent" message.what is the problem?

Comment: first things to do: wrap you form in `<body>` - html is invalid markup - next! var_dump $_POST to see if anything at all gets passed

Comment: `<form>` tags belong in a `<body>` tag. Start by creating a properly formatted HTML Document

Comment: I think it's easier to use just `if($_POST){}`

Comment: It works, dude, when i click Submit Query message = "sent"???

Comment: @SuperDJ But that does not tell you if the `$_POST` array contains the field you are then going to attempt to use

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs its also not working with `<body>` tag.and could you please explain more about next! var_dump $_POST.

Comment: I've posted an answer...which works, and takes into account all the above.

Comment: @erfan.sajjadie you do in your php script `var_dump($_POST);` outside of the if statement - this will show you what actually gets postefd

Comment: @SuperDJ also that would work if fields are posted as null because $_POST has data in it - it will fail pretty much 99% of checks

Comment: It says "not sent" because on page load, nothing has been posted at that point. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make sure your markup is valid. Note that you have some spaces where there should not be spaces (e.g. `name ="name"`). At a minimum you should have a blank HTML document, with your contents inside a `<body>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="read.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It's unclear from your question whether the above form is inside `read.php` or a separate script?

If they are separate (e.g. the form is in `index.php`) then run `index.php` in your browser. It should post to `read.php` which must be in the same relative directory. If the form and PHP is inside the *same script*, then run `read.php` in your browser.

With the PHP itself you are best off trying to debug this by outputting the contents of the post, e.g.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

If it works, you will get an array which contains the form contents after posting. This will only appear *after* you have filled in the `name` field and pressed the Submit button, e.g.

```
array(1) { ["name"]=> string(4) "andy" }
```

Going back to the code in your question...If all of your code is in the same script, **it will say "not sent" on page load, because nothing has been posted at that point**. It will only output "sent" once you've filled in the `name` field and pressed the Submit button.

You were wondering why this "works" with the GET method. Well, the reason is because GET will append the form fields to the URL. On page load you run `index.php`. There's no `$_GET` parameters. After submitting the form, the URL would be manipulated (e.g. `index.php?name=andy`). So on page load it says "not sent" but then once it has `?name=andy` in the URL it will say "sent" because that's a GET parameter.

Comment: files are are separate and in same path when I use `var_dump($_POST)`   
 I get this message  `array(0) { }` while when I use `GET` method everything is ok.

Comment: @erfan.sajjadie which is entirely correct. It will only show output AFTER you have filled in and submitted the form. Try that, do you get the array being output? I've added an explanation for `$_GET`

Comment: What's your intention for how it should work? Do you want it to say *nothing* on page load? And when the user presses Submit it does the check? Your code will always have output  because you're not even doing a check to see whether the form has been submitted - you're just saying "has the `name` field been posted?" which has a yes/no (sent/not sent) outcome at any given time.

Comment: thank you for your help @Andy I get what was problem.your  explanations help me a lot good luck my friend.